# Angular $scope not updating in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a strange problem with Angulars scope. I worked with it for a while and everything is great, but in this little snippet the $scope will not change. Any idea?
($scope.projects and $scope.commentText, the post returns the data successfully)

Model from HTM:

```
 <textarea ng-model="commentText" class="form-control"
                                              placeholder="Enter your comment..." rows="3"></textarea>
                                    <br>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" ng-click="postComment(projects[0]._id, commentText)">Post comment</a>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.postComment = function (project_id, comment) {
    console.log(project_id, comment);
    if (comment && $scope.user) {
        var body = {
            project: project_id,
            text: comment.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />'),
            user: $scope.user.nickname,
            date: new Date()

        };
        $http.post('/api/projects/comment', body)
            .success(function (data) {
                data.comments.map(function (comment) {
                    comment.text = $sce.trustAsHtml(comment.text)
                });
                $scope.projects[0] = data;
                $scope.commentText = "";
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                console.log('Error: ' + error);

            });
    }
```

Comment: could you reproduce it in fiddle ?

Comment: I had to reduce it a bit, but it is working there. http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9756/

Comment: the code is right just check whether you get call back in success what are you trying to do in $sce.trustAsHtml(comment.text) is $sce dependency in controller and its libraries included don't see in fiddle at least?

Comment: I get a success call back and console logs are also working. I just can't access $scope.commentText anymore. If I log it the console it is always null. Right before the function everything is working.
BTW $sce is to escape a String as HTML

Comment: $sce should be added in controller dependency and santize library must have been loaded see your console you might be getting some error

Comment: mhh...I got no errors and it is working in other functions already.
Aned even without, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
Everything was working fine...the problem is I can't change the content of the textarea with the commong $scope.textarea = "".

I used jquery with $("#text-area").val("") for this.

Comment: This does not sound like the right approach. Generally speaking, jQuery shouldn't used with Angular to do Angular's tasks.

Comment: You are right, but I found it on some other questions that there are problem with scope and textareas. Any idea on how to do this with angular?